# CompletableFuture exceptionally breaks the work chain

Tags: java-8

The idea of using `CompletableFuture` is because it offers a chain, while the first several steps encapsulate beans before the last step uses it. Because any exception may happen in these steps and `exceptionally` is used to handle error. However, `exceptionally` only accepts `Throwable` argument and so far I haven't found a way to grab those encapsulated beans.

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::msgSource)
            .thenApply(this::sendMsg).exceptionally(this::errorHandler).thenAccept(this::saveResult)
public List<Msg> msgSource() // take message from somewhere.
public List<Msg> sendMsg(List<Msg>) // exceptions may happen like 403 or timeout
public List<Msg> errorHandler() // set a success flag to false in Msg.
public void saveResult(List<Msg>) // save send result like success or false in data center.
```

In the above example, comments are the working flow. However, since `errorHandler` neither accepts `List<Msg>` nor passes it on, so the chain is broken. How to get the return from `msgSource`?

EDIT

```
public class CompletableFutureTest {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompletableFutureTest.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFutureTest test = new CompletableFutureTest();
        CompletableFuture future = new CompletableFuture();
        future.supplyAsync(test::msgSource)
            .thenApply(test::sendMsg).exceptionally(throwable -> {
            List<String> list = (List<String>) future.join(); // never complete
            return list;
        }).thenAccept(test::saveResult);
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private List<String> saveResult(List<String> list) {
        return list;
    }

    private List<String> sendMsg(List<String> list) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public List<String> msgSource() {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add("1");
        result.add("2");
        return result;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *chain* implies that each node, i.e. completion stage, uses the result of the previous one. But if the previous stage failed with an exception, there is no such result. It’s a special property of your `sendMsg` stage that its result is just the same value as it received from the previous stage, but that has no influence on the logic nor API design. If `sendMsg` fails with an exception, it has no result that the exception handler could use.

If you want to use the result of the `msgSource` stage in the exceptional case, you don’t have a linear chain any more. But `CompletableFuture` does allow to model arbitrary dependency graphs, not just linear chains, so you can express it like

```
CompletableFuture<List<Msg>> source = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::msgSource);
source.thenApply(this::sendMsg)
      .exceptionally(throwable -> {
          List<Msg> list = source.join();
          for(Msg m: list) m.success = false;
          return list;
      })
      .thenAccept(this::saveResult);
```

However, there is no semantic difference nor advantage over

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    List<Msg> list = msgSource();
    try {
        list = sendMsg(list);
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        for(Msg m: list) m.success = false;
    }
    saveResult(list);
});
```

which expresses the same logic as an ordinary code flow.

Comment: wouldn't that set the `success = false` for all `Msg` if a single one failed?

Comment: @Eugene: sure. If `sendMsg(List<Msg>)` fails, it implies a failure for the entire list. That’s how the question’s code is designed, which applies to the usage of `CompletableFuture`, as well as the methods receiving and returning a `List`.

Comment: if `exceptionally` forgets about all the manipulations that its former works did on messages, then its return would be much useless. But your 1st code segment shows there is a way to take out the former work indeed, just with a prerequisite that one *knows ahead which work causes the exception*. What I thought was getting the argument (in this case its `List<Msg>`) of the function that throws exception in `exceptionally`. Sometimes this chain could be longer and try catch in everyone of them could be mostly meaningless.

Comment: @Tiina: Isn’t it always the same list, regardless of what actual work has been done to the `Msg` instances? The work that has been done to the `Msg` instances is not lost (otherwise it would be pointless to change their `success` state).

Comment: @Holger thx. I sort of had an impression that the OP might want to not fail all of them, but it might just be me.

Comment: @Holger it is the same list, until it meets `exceptionally`. It accepts a `R apply(T t);`, I wish it could accept a `R apply(T t, R r);` or at least wraps `R` in `T`. But I tried your 1st code segment, and it never completes? `source.join();` hangs.

Comment: The action chained to `source` via `source.thenApply(…).exceptionally(action)` will only be executed if the prerequisite `source` has been completed. Therefore, at this point `source.join()` should never block at all.

Comment: @Holger Please see the image I uploaded. I have tried to take the `.join` out (enclosing area from `exceptionally` to `main`), still hangs. BTW, I think, `CompletableFuture.handle` gives both `throwable` and `list`? unlike `exceptionally` which only gives `throwable`. If true, then I guess I was intend to use `handle`

Comment: @Tiina: your code is not what I have posted. There is no sense in creating another `CompletableFuture` and calling the **static** method `supplyAsync` on it. There is, of course, no relationship between this uncompleted future and the future returned by the `static` method `supplyAsync`. In my code, the future returned by `supplyAsync` is used. Regarding the other question, no `handle` doesn’t change the fact that a stage can only have one result, a value or a failure. You have two parameters to be able to receiver either, but the other will be `null`.

Comment: @Holger when `new CompletableFuture`, and `.join` would return a non-null `result` or block and wait for a result, but `future` is never given a task, so it hangs, now I see.